What is this sub-rule in grammars called?
Suppose I'm writing a grammar rule for arithmetics, and for additions, I got this:
Additive-Expression
: Multiplicative-Expression
| Additive-Expression ("+"|"-") Multiplicative-Expression
;

The multiplicative rule is involved to establish the precedence of operators. Q: What's the name of the rule to the right of the colon ":"? Fall-back? Pass-thru? What are the references I can learn more?

Not backed by any real reference, but "atom unit" may be descriptive enough.

Or "the atom production rule", or just the "atom rule".

I'd have called it the "base" or "limiting" rule/case (like any recursive definition) or the "degenerate rule/case" as there's no addition going on, after the mathematical use eg "degenerate triangle" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(mathematics)

@jonathanjo Degeneracy sounds most descriptive.
